# Golang xml encoding="windows-1251"

Tags: xml, golang, utf-8, xmlparser, cp1251

Пишу парсер для xml файлов, но проблема в том, что в файле кодировка:
encoding="windows-1251".
Когда перевел кодировку в ut8 то следующем кодом смог распарсить документ.

```
for _, file := range files {
            _, filename := utils.Unzip("/Users/farex/upload/"+file.Filename, "/Users/farex/upload/")
            _ = filename
            ///---------- Open our xmlFile-----------------------
            for _, file := range filename {
                xmlFile, err := os.Open("/Users/farex/upload/" + file)
                // if we os.Open returns an error then handle it
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                }
                fmt.Println("Successfully Opened " + file)

                if utils.Cut(file, 1) == "H" {

                    defer xmlFile.Close()

                    byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
                    var zl_list models.ZL_LIST

                    xml.Unmarshal(byteValue, &zl_list)

                    fmt.Println("---ZGLV---")
                    fmt.Println("VERSION" + zl_list.ZGLV[0].VERSION)
                    fmt.Println("DATA" + zl_list.ZGLV[0].DATA)
                    fmt.Println("FILENAME" + zl_list.ZGLV[0].FILENAME)
                    fmt.Println("SD_z" + zl_list.ZGLV[0].SD_Z)
```

Это все работает, но задача парсить не Документы в формате utf8 , а в cp-1251.
Как можно "конвертировать" cp-1251 в utf-8 ?
Добавил меторд:

```
func EncodeWindows1251(ba []uint8) []uint8 {
    enc := charmap.Windows1251.NewEncoder()
    out, _ := enc.String(string(ba))
    return []uint8(out)
}
```

и соответственно вызываю его:

```
byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)
a := EncodeWindows1251(byteValue)
var zl_list  models.ZL_LIST
xml.Unmarshal(a, &zl_list)
```

Тоже не работает...
Но если из документа убрать строку `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>`.
То все работает и документ парсится... Неужели придется регуляркой удалять эту строчку в документе?

Добавил метод наисанный ниже и за импортировал.        "golang.org/x/text/encoding/charmap".
Но:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Образец файла xml [тут](https://yadi.sk/d/ZKlwoTdU3Mc636) кодировка cp-1251

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для этого существует поле `Decoder.CharsetReader`:

```
// CharsetReader, if non-nil, defines a function to generate
// charset-conversion readers, converting from the provided
// non-UTF-8 charset into UTF-8. If CharsetReader is nil or
// returns an error, parsing stops with an error. One of the
// the CharsetReader's result values must be non-nil.
CharsetReader func(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error)
```

Использовать можно так:

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(xmlFile)
d.CharsetReader = func(charset string, input io.Reader) (io.Reader, error) {
    switch charset {
    case "windows-1251":
        return charmap.Windows1251.NewDecoder().Reader(input), nil
    default:
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("unknown charset: %s", charset)
    }
}
err := d.Decode(&zlList)
```

Comment: извиняюсь, но непойму как его использовать в моем коде., вроде сделал как вы написали, но по прежнему не распарсивает

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев Во-первых, выражайтесь чётче. Что значит "не распарсивает"? Во-вторых, предоставьте образец документа.

Comment: Образец документа добавил в описания темы

Comment: не распарсивает это падает в панику.

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев https://play.golang.org/p/q-OUWR8AxJ - у меня работает и не паникует, корректно выводя две фамилии.

Comment: Уже, разобрался. С вашим кодом все нормально... спасибо